# What operations were carried out by the partisans of the Chernihiv junction in the Great Patriotic War?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, reference

I am interested in finding out more about the Chernihiv partisan junction which was an important force throughout the Great Patriotic War, and their leader [Alexei Fyodorovich Fyodorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleksiy_Fedorov).

Unfortunately, I am not educated enough to do some organized search as I do not have much clue which other forces throughout the war might've collided with the junction. I didn't have much luck online. I found [an interesting article about the junction's operations in Bryanskaya and Orlovskaya oblasts from the autumn of 1942 to the winter of 1943](https://moluch.ru/archive/53/7078/) (it is in Russian, sorry).

Does anyone have any other material to study to organize one's understanding of operations carried out by the junction throughout the Great Patriotic War?

Comment: Please revise question based on our policy on [reference requests](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4260/1401)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thank you. I edited the 2nd extract so the question falls under category (3) according to the post you linked. Does it fit?

Comment: The H:SE community will need to decide it if is in scope; I merely wanted to make you aware of an opportunity to revise to be _more likely_ to be in scope. Two notes - (1) the recommended approach to case #3 is to close the question, and (2) There is no _question_ in your title; questions where the title asks a question are more likely to get answers.

Comment: Well, there is lot of information on Fyodorov on Russian internet. Casual search gives :http://www.warheroes.ru/hero/hero.asp?Hero_id=1193     https://zen.yandex.ru/media/razdolbayputeshesvennik/vydaiusciesia-partizanskie-komandiry-aleksei-fedorov-5dc271e11febd400ae31e271

Comment: I'm sure you could find more if you do your search in Russian and using Russian search engines.